# How to mock a new object in mockito

Tags: mocking, mockito, powermockito

Hi guys im currently writing mockito tests and i came across something that im failing to mock see below :

`SEOKey seoKey = new SEOKey(seoEntityId, SEOEntityType.valueOf(seoEntityType));`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How do you fail to mock that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Mockito allows you to mock `new` methods. What you need to do is use the PowerMockito `whenNew` method.

Something like this (feel free to add your arguments if it is important):

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(SEOKey.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(seoKeyMock);
```

Remember to add the class you are trying to test into the `@PrepareForTest` annotation with your class declaration. This should be for the class you are testing, not the class for which you call the `new` method.

Answer (score -2):

You may either

```
@Mock
private SEOKey key;

@Before
public void setup(){
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

then the member gets mocked.

Another possibility is doing the mocking directly in the test method:

```
SEOKey key = Mockito.mock(SEOKey.class);
```